# Get null values from facetable fields in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Is it possible to get the null values from a facetable field?

My index model looks something like the class below.
Notice that the `Category` field is facetable but can also contain `null`.

```cs
public class ProductIndex
{
    [SearchableField(IsFilterable = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [SearchableField(IsFilterable = true, IsFacetable = true)]
    public string? Category { get; set; }
}
```

When I am searching the index to get a list of all avaliable categories it contains all non-null values.
But i would like the list to contain `null` as a value for the category.

How can I ensure the list of facets contain the `null` values?

---

I am aware that I can solve this issue by inserting a "blank" value in the search index for each null value.
But as `null` is a valid value in this context, I dont think this is a good solution.